# How to Prevent Stack Trace from Spring Rest API Exception Handler returning HTTP status 400

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to handle Validation exception in Spring Rest service like code given below:

```
@Produces("application/json")
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<ValidationErrorDTO> processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
        List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();
        ResponseEntity<ValidationErrorDTO> re = new ResponseEntity<>(processFieldErrors(fieldErrors), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);   
        return re;
    }
```

However when this code executes, it returns stack trace appended to the JSON response. I want to get rid of this stack trace and only return JSON error response. Is this possible with Spring 3.1?

```
{"fieldErrors":    
[{"field":"type","message":"Pattern.shippingAddress.type"}]}&lt;pre&gt;javax.servlet.ServletException: 400 Bad Request null
        at com.ebay.raptor.kernel.dispatcher.HttpDispatchCommand.execute(HttpDispatchCommand.java:142)
        at com.ebay.ebox.pres.cmd.preshandler.CommandDispatchHandler.handleRequest(CommandDispatchHandler.java:59)
        at com.ebay.ebox.pres.cmd.preshandler.CommandDispatchHandler.handleRequest(CommandDispatchHandler.java:13)
        at com.ebay.ebox.pres.cmd.preshandler.CommandHandlerFactory$CalHandler.handleRequest(CommandHandlerFactory.java:114)
        at com.ebay.ebox.pres.cmd.preshandler.CommandHandlerFactory$CalHandler.handleRequest(CommandHandlerFactory.java:75)
        at com.ebay.kernel.pipeline.RequestPipeline.invoke(RequestPipeline.java:18)
        at com.ebay.kernel.pipeline.RequestPipeline.invoke(RequestPipeline.java:12)
        at com.ebay.kernel.pipeline.BasePipeline.callHandler(BasePipeline.java:75)
        at com.ebay.kernel.pipeline.BasePipeline.execute(BasePipeline.java:53)
        at com.ebay.ebox.pres.stage.BaseCommandRequestStageImpl.doWork(BaseCommandRequestStageImpl.java:64)
        at com.ebay.kernel.stage.StageDriver.execute(StageDriver.java:55)
        at com.ebay.ebox.pres.cmd.WebCommandImpl.execute(WebCommandImpl.java:30)
        at com.ebay.raptor.web.RaptorFrontController.process(RaptorFrontController.java:338)
        at com.ebay.raptor.web.RaptorFrontController.doPost(RaptorFrontController.java:554)
        at com.ebay.raptor.web.RaptorGenericController.service(RaptorGenericController.java:64)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at com.ebay.raptor.kernel.filter.RaptorDispatchFilter.doFilter(RaptorDispatchFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:195)
        at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:266)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    &lt;/pre&gt;
```

Comment: There must be somewhere a second filter that append the stack trace. I think, (Because of the stacktrace) that this filter is registered somewhere in the web.xml - maybe you post the web.xml, that one can have a look at this, and point at the spot.

Comment: There are no filters mapped in web.xml and also no servlets except Spring's dispatcher servlet.

Comment: what is: com.ebay.raptor.kernel.dispatcher.HttpDispatchCommand

Comment: It's an internal framework class.

Comment: I verified that if I do not use @ResponseBody annotation and instead write to response output print stream directly this stack trace is not added. It is only added when I use this ResponseBody Annotation and set HttpStatus to anything other than 200.

Answer (score 8):

You can just add the application property `server.error.include-stacktrace=never` which responds for including stack trace into 400 responses.

Comment: by default, `server.error.include-stacktrace=never`

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public ModelAndView methodArgumentError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception exception) {
    return new JsonError(exception.getMessage()).asModelAndView();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could in your *MethodArgumentNotValidException* set the stack trace to null if the error is only being returned to the user and not be used for debugging.

Or alternatively, you could just override the *getStackTrace()* with a *@JsonIgnore* annotation

```
@JsonIgnore
@Override
public StackTraceElement[] getStackTrace() {
    return super.getStackTrace();
}
```

EDIT: I tried all the other solutions but none worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
```

Use @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) on your method it will work

Answer (score 0):

It is uncommon to use both: `@ResponseBody` and `ResponseEntity`. I think you should clearly decide what you want to do. - And then you should check your internal framework class `com.ebay.raptor.kernel.dispatcher.HttpDispatchCommand`, because this is the one that throws the exception.

Comment: I tried without ResponseEntity also and the problem is same.
As you pointed out I am currently analyzing this framework class com.ebay.raptor.kernel.dispatcher.HttpDispatchCommand.
Right now it's highly suspected to be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler way to do it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


System.setProperty("server.error.include-message", "never");
System.setProperty("server.error.include-stacktrace", "never");

//You can also change other important properties with this method, for example:

// System.setProperty("server.port", "8081");
// System.setProperty("server.servlet.context-path", "/api");

SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);

}
```

The response will look like this;

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-12-30T19:23:24.002+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "path": "/test"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Aspectj for these purposes. Example http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/

You should write an aspect, which will catch your exception.

Example:

```
@Aspect
public class AroundExample {
 @Around
 pointcut = "execution(* your.package.Class.processValidationError(..))",
      throwing= "error")
 public Object doSomeStuff(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Throwable error) throws Throwable {

    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs(); // change the args if you want to
    Object retVal = pjp.proceed(args); // run the actual method (or don't)
    return retVal; // return the return value (or something else)
  }

}
```

Comment: The `@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)` allready catches the exception, so there's no need for AspectJ here.

Comment: But it doesnt return needed value.

Comment: No exception is thrown in `processValidationError` ! So your advice would never been called. It is allready an exception handler for exception occuring during the treatment of a request - read spring framework documentation about `ExceptionHandler` ...